# Why won't my creature parent to its armature

Tags: armature, parent

When I try to parent my students armature, an error occurs that says, "Bone heat weighting error on more than one bone" I'm not sure how to correct this. I looked to see if it was symmetrical and it seems to be. Any help would be great. I copied the link so you can see the file.

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36448

Thanks!

Comment: To increase clarity please include one or more screen shots. Please show some success and the failure in your images.

Comment: If you could add the steps you take in the .blend file to trigger that error, that would help as well.

Comment: Switch to Object mode.
Right-click the creature to select it.
Press and hold SHIFT and right-click the armature.
TIP: Zoom in to make it easier to click on the bones.
Press CTRL + P to make the armature a parent of the body. In the Make Parent menu that appears, left-click Armature Deform, With Automatic Weights entry.
Select just the creature, go to Object Modifiers, and make sure Bind to Vertex Groups is checkmarked.

@atomicbezierslinger these are the instructions the students have

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh i listed the instructions above

Answer (score 2):

Your armature's shape is extremely different from the creature's shape: so the algorithm that should assign weight automatically can't decide which vertices to assign to which bone.

In this case you should choose the "with empty groups" option: it will create an empty vertex group for every bone of your armature.

Then you will have to weight them manually. Using weight paint; or selecting a vertex group, in edit mode selecting the vertices you want to be moved, and click assign in the vertex group mesh tab of the properties panel.

The corrispondence between bones and vertex groups is made by names.

Comment: I haven't used wet paint before, what would be the steps to do that?

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing this right. Everything I try, I still get that error

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing this file, and there seems to be more than one problem with the mesh and the armature.

I've been able to bind the mesh to a single bone with automatic weights, but haven't been able to find a step by step process to get your mesh bound to the current armature as of yet.

Some of the issues with the mesh are:

- poor topology including a lot of pinching
- many doubled vertices
- too many vertices, should have a simpler base mesh with a subdiv modifier instead
- the face has a lot of separate small pieces
- there's no root bone
- the bone sizes don't match the arm/leg sizes

If you redo the armature, it's important that the first bone (hip or root) shares the same origin point as the mesh. If I figure out an exact fix I'll let you know.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking at it. I have been spending hours trying to figure it out. I will try to redo the armature for him and see what happens. Any help would be appreciated!